# Liveable or livable?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives, able-eable

would you rather use liveable or livable? As in an accessible and liveable/livable city needs appropriate infrastructures - for example.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial research. For example, what do dictionaries say about the spelling, and why are they insufficient? When someone posts an answer here, he or she is going to check the dictionary first, so if that is unsatisfactory you have only wasted a volunteer's time. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

It is a question of AmE vs BrE spelling. As the [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/spelling/liveable-or-livable/) notes:

> - Liveable is an adjective, the noun forms are liveability and liveableness. ***Liveable is the preferred British spelling.***
> - ***Livable is the preferred American spelling***, it is gaining acceptance around the world. Livable is an adjective, the noun forms are livability and livableness.